# Spring JPA increase/decrease balance

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm thinking how develop the management of the balance of a sms gateway. In short, I've many customers and every customer has a balance in €.
Every time a sms is sent, the balance should be decreased. I can also recharge the account with a deposit.

My question is which is the best way to model this scenario. The first idea was to use a @Formula to get the balance without store it in the db. But with thousands or maybe millions of rows this method will be every time slower. So I think it's not scalable and it's not efficient.

Using a column for the balance instead I risk to slow down the entire system due to the concurrency problems. I have to use a PESSIMISTIC LOCK every time I want send a sms. So I reduce the concurrency (ofter customers wants send hundreds sms in few seconds)

So I ask if there is a smart way to manage this. I'm sure there is a smart way otherwise I can't explain how many very big providers can manage millions of sms in a single day.

Just to summarize my entity customer would be similar to:

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable{
     private String name;
     //Solution with persisted column
     private BigDecimal balance;

     //solution using formula instead of a real column in the db
     @Formula("CAST((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(r.importo),0) FROM RicaricaTelefonica r WHERE r.cliente_id=id)-(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(t.importoVendita),0) from Telefonata t WHERE t.cliente=id) AS DECIMAL(10,2))")
private BigDecimal balance= BigDecimal.ZERO;
 }
```

The query into @Formula is only an example, don't see at it but consider the idea.

======== UPDATE ===========
I had another idea maybe smarter. Use an hybrid solution. Create a new object Balance that store the balance in a specific time, and using @Formula to calculate balance based on the last Balance saved on the db + all sms sent from that moment.

In this way I can save the balance on the DB every day, or every 4 hours using a pessimistic write so to presenve the correctness of the balance.
The real time balance of the user will be a formula like

```
@Formula("SELECT * FROM Balance ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1"-"SELECT SUM(price) FROM Sms WHERE date>=balanceDate"+"SELECT * from Deposit WHERE date>=balanceDate")
```

What do you think?

Comment: consider using blockchain in this case :-)

Comment: This can be solved using two entities. The Customer entity is should contain a total balance. And another entity let say Transactions. Transactions will have all credit or debit transactions. This way you can calculate balance in app code and main entity and details in transactions

Comment: @SangramJadhav how you update the total balance? I've yet an entity "Transactions" where there are credit or debit transaction. But using Formula to calculate on the fly the balance is too expensive. On the other hand have a total balance present concurrency problems. Can you explain better your idea? Thanks